# How can I force the next tick immediately in CreateJS 1.0.0+?

Tags: createjs, easeljs, adobe-animate

Under the 2015 version of CreateJS, it's safe to force the next stage tick immediately by calling update(). I've used this in a timeline "change" event handler to force the timeline to stay synced with realtime.

But under 1.0.0, even though the order of event execution seems to be unchanged, using this technique can now cause root timeline frame code to execute prematurely or be skipped over. This problem persisted even after I deferred the update() call to a setTimeout zero-delay event, which executed after CreateJS had finished all its tasks for the current frame.

So what is now the "correct" way to force CreateJS to immediately render the next tick instead of waiting for it?

Note that this is all within the Adobe Animate environment.